# get user info using access-token Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I have worked with *omniauth* using `api-key` ,`api-secret` pair . but what if I have the access token and I don't want to use key/secret to fetch user data . How can I do it for *Facebook* and *Google+* . Any help will be appreciated . I'm lost in it

Answer (score 2):

For google+, user info can be retrieved from google using access_token by sending request to their provided endpoint.

```rb
response = HTTParty.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo",
  headers: { 'Authorization' => "OAuth #{access_token}" }
)
```